# Viewed links on Hot Network Questions unclear

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, hot-questions

When you visit a Hot Network Question, if the question appears in the list again, the link is styled differently to show that the question link has been previously visited.

However, when visiting the different SE sites, they are styled differently from one another. I understand each site is styled differently, however it is difficult to know which questions have already been viewed depending on what site you're currently on.

On codegolf, for example, viewed links are darkened so in the image below I have viewed the first 3 questions, but not the next 2. On worldbuilding, it is the other way round - viewed links are made lighter meaning, in the image below, I have viewed the first 6 questions, but not the next 6. Other sites also have different styles; sometimes the viewed link has been changed so little, it is difficult to distinguish between a itself and a non-viewed link.

At a glance, this makes it difficult to see which questions are new, as it depends on what site you're currently on to determine what styling you should be looking for. My question is, **is there anything that can be done to the styling across all sites to ensure consistency?**

#### codegolf

[image]

#### worldbuilding

[image]